# asynchronously get all files that match a specific extension from a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function whose job it is to return all the mp3 files from a directory (ignoring subdirectories) as an array. The user gives me the full directory path. For some reason it seems to include every file in the directory. I've narrowed it down to the fact that my filter method seems to execute despite it being async and being `await`ed, but I'm not sure how to fix it so that it gives me back *only* files that end in `.mp3`?

As an example, I provided the following path:

```
/mnt/d/Music/S/Square Enix/2020 - Final Fantasy VII Remake Mini Soundtrack [v0]/
├── 01 - The Prelude.mp3
├── 02 - Tifa's Theme.mp3
├── 03 - Shinra's Theme.mp3
├── 04 - Scorpion Sentinel.mp3
├── 05 - On Our Way.mp3
├── 06 - The Turks' Theme.mp3
├── 07 - Let The Battles Begin!.mp3
├── 08 - Flowers Blooming in the Church.mp3
├── 09 - Hurry!.mp3
├── 10 - Main Theme of FINAL FANTASY VII.mp3
├── 11 - Lay Down Some Rubber.mp3
├── 12 - Stand Up.mp3
└── Folder.jpg3
```

The result should include every file *except* `Folder.jpg` - but when I run this code:

```
  async getAllFiles (directory, extension) {
    let files = await fs.readdir(directory)
    files = await Promise.all(files.filter(async file => {
      const filePath = join(directory, file)
      const stats = await fs.stat(filePath)
      return stats.isFile() && extname(filePath) === extension
    }))
    return files
  }
```

the array I get back looks like this:

```
0:"01 - The Prelude.mp3"
1:"02 - Tifa's Theme.mp3"
2:"03 - Shinra's Theme.mp3"
3:"04 - Scorpion Sentinel.mp3"
4:"05 - On Our Way.mp3"
5:"06 - The Turks' Theme.mp3"
6:"07 - Let The Battles Begin!.mp3"
7:"08 - Flowers Blooming in the Church.mp3"
8:"09 - Hurry!.mp3"
9:"10 - Main Theme of FINAL FANTASY VII.mp3"
10:"11 - Lay Down Some Rubber.mp3"
11:"12 - Stand Up.mp3"
12:"Folder.jpg"
```

Is there anything I can do to get this working as intended?

Comment: When you do `await fs.stat()`, are you trying to await the regular `fs.stat()`?  If so, you can't do that.  It doesn't return a promise so `await` won't do anything useful with it.  Instead, use `fs.promises.stat()`.  That will work.

Comment: And, you can't use `.filter()` when returning a promise.  That won't work at all.  `.filter()` expects you to return a boolean, not a promise.  Switch to a regular `for` loop and then use `async/await`.  Much, much simpler to code.

Comment: ah - I forgot some context for my question. I'm actually using `require('fs').promises` which (if I'm remembering correctly) returns fs methods in a promisified form

Comment: funny thing - I tried the synchronous version of this code (just to clarify) and it worked perfectly, so you hit the nail on the head @jfriend00 it 100% was the filter getting back a Promise, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `withFileTypes` option for `fsp.readdir()` and make this a lot easier:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

async getAllFiles (directory, extension) {
   let files = await fsp.readdir(directory, {withFileTypes: true});
   return files
       .filter(f => f.isFile() && path.extname(f.name) === extension)
       .map(f => f.name);
}
```

Or, if you want to return the full path names:

```
const fsp = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');

async getAllFiles (directory, extension) {
   let files = await fsp.readdir(directory, {withFileTypes: true});
   return files
      .filter(f => f.isFile() && path.extname(f.name) === extension)
      .map(f => path.join(directory, f.name));
}
```

Your current code won't work because `.filter()` expects you to return it a boolean, but you're returning a promise so that will never filter anything out.

Note: I never name `fs.promises` as `fs` in my code because it hopelessly confuses people who read the code.  I personally use `fsp` to represent `fs.promises`, but anything that isn't `fs` will clue in the reader that this isn't the normal top level `fs`.

Also, make sure that `extension` contains the leading `.` because `path.extname()` will leave the period on.

---

FYI, for a nice function for listing files in a directory, see https://github.com/jfriend00/fs-common/blob/master/fslist.js (not in NPM yet, you'd have to just copy it).  After importing, you would just do:

```
listDirectory(directory, {matchWhat: "ext", match: "mp3"}).then(files => {
    console.log(files);
});
```

There are a bunch of options for what to list or match, including regex on name or extension, recursive, callbacks, case insensitive matching, include directories or not, etc...

Comment: oh man this is comprehensive, accomplishes what I need to and makes things easier to understand! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`extname(filePath)` returns the extension preceded by a point (as in ".ts", ".js", etc.). I'm assuming you're passing an extension without a leading point, which leads to your filter function returning false (`".ts"` !== `"ts"`).

EDIT: For whatever reason, removing the `async` keyword from the filtering function (alongside proper fixes, such as replacing `fs.promises.stat` by `fs.statSync`), the filtering now seems to work properly.